# Passing parameters at runtime to chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am running chef-solo

At runtime I would like to pass the install location of the software & other parameters that I am trying to install using chef-solo

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i'd recommend using chef-client in `-z` mode rather than chef-solo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-j` option chef-solo (or chef-client) to provide this kind of thing, but make sure you format it correctly. Another option is to have your recipe code read in a config file from a designated path (usually JSON or Yaml formatted) and use that in the rest of the recipe code. Environment variables are an option too, but I would avoid it as you may be surprised at when env vars get unset (sudo, ssh, etc).

Comment: Is there a link you can provide for some info on this -j option